# What is wrong with my current WPF project that I can't import FXG files? Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, user-interface, expression-blend, blend

I'm working on a WPF project, in Blend, and wanted to import an Adobe FXG file, but that command is disabled.  The other commands under File>Import are enabled.

Also, I created a new blank WPF project and the command is enabled, I can import the file normally (it gives me the symbols to select etc. and brings them into the project as usercontrols).

I also tried a workaround by just adding the file to the project, it shows up in the list but the symbols are not usercontrols.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I restarted Blend, nothing changed.  I restarted my laptop, and now it's enabled.  Very odd.